# Replacing special character in string not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

I have a long string, which includes the text `Your Sunday evening order with Uber Eats\nTo: test@email.com\n\n\n[image: map]\n\n[image: Uber logo]\n\xe2\x82\xac17.50\nThanks for choosing Uber,`

I am trying to replace '\xe2\x82\xac' with 'EUR' in Python 3.6

If I print the string, I see that it is preceded by b, i.e. it is a byte literal.

```
 b'<div dir="ltr"><br ...' etc.
```

I cannot encode it (`html = html.encode('UTF-8')`), because then I get `a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` nor can I decode it (`'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`)

I have tried:

```
html = html.replace(u"\xe2\x82\xac","EUR")
html = html.replace(u'\xe2\x82\xac',"EUR")
html = html.replace('\xe2\x82\xac',"EUR")
html = html.replace(u"€","EUR")
```

None of these work.

`html.decode("utf-8")` gets me an error `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`.

For context, the string is generated by reading the content of an e-mail with the mailbox library:

```
for message in mbox:
   for part in message.walk():
       html = str(part.get_payload(decode=True))
```

Comment: Your first line of `replace` worked for me, in python 3.6

Comment: `html.replace('\xe2\x82\xac',"EUR")` just works in utf-8 text.

Comment: It also works when I copy/paste the string from my question into python. However it does not work on my original string, which I copy/pasted originally into my question. This is a bit puzzling.

Comment: I'm using python 3.6 too and here works. Check if your python file is encoded as UTF-8 Unicode text or try use `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on the top

Comment: @MateusMilanez I have done that but no change. I think it has something to do with the type of encoding/object that this string is, but type(str) just gives me <class 'str'>

Comment: Note that the `u"string"` prefix is unnecessary in python3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
html = html.replace(r"\xe2\x82\xac", "EUR")
```

So that the string `\xe2\x82\xac` is replaced to EUR. Assuming that `\` is literally on your html.

Otherwise, you should

```
html = html.replace('\u20ac', 'EUR')
```

But this seems not the case, because with your unicode symbols, it do not work.

Do not assume that Python use UTF-8 in the strings (in fact it do not use UTF-8 internally).

Note: Python uses UTF-16 (or UTF-32) so `\xe2\x82\xac` would never been written by Python (from a decoded string). So or `\` was literal, or some output process mangled it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import unicodedata
jil = """"Your Sunday evening order with Uber Eats\nTo: test@email.com\n\n\n[image: map]\n\n[image: Uber logo]\n\xe2\x82\xac17.50\nThanks for choosing Uber,"""
data = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", jil)
print(data)
>>>" Your Sunday evening order with Uber Eats
To: test@email.com


[image: map]

[image: Uber logo]
â¬17.50
Thanks for choosing Uber,
```

Answer (score 0):

it does not work that way.

```
html="Your Sunday evening order with Uber Eats\nTo: test@email.com\n\n\n[image: map]\n\n[image: Uber logo]\n\xe2\x82\xac17.50\nThanks for choosing Uber,"
html = html.replace(u"\xe2\x82\xac","EUR")
html = html.replace(u'\xe2\x82\xac',"EUR")
html = html.replace('\xe2\x82\xac',"EUR")
html = html.replace(u"€","EUR")

html = html.encode("utf-8",'strict');

print("Encoded String: " + str(html))
print("Decoded String: " + html.decode("utf-8",'strict'))
```